# Flask + Nginx + uwsgi + telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, flask

Есть бот на веб-хуках, пытаюсь его запустить в прод, но чёт не выходит.
Снизу будут все конфиги, и код, буду признателен если поможете)

Код самого бота!

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)

app = flask.Flask(__name__)


def get_info_into_DB(path):
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        data = pickle.load(f)
    return data


# Empty webserver index, return nothing, just http 200
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'HEAD'])
def index():
    return ''


# Process webhook calls
@app.route(WEBHOOK_URL_PATH, methods=['POST','GET'])
def webhook():
    global post_info
    global post_id
    if flask.request.headers.get('content-type') == 'application/json':
        json_string = flask.request.get_json()
        #print(json_string)
        if 'message' in json_string.keys():
            if 'entities' in json_string['message'].keys():
                post_id = json_string['message']['text'].split(' ')[-1]
                if post_id.split('_')[0] == 'continuation':
                    post_info = get_info_into_DB('/home/nikita/bots/message_bot/DB/post_with_continuation.pickle').get(f'{post_id.split("_")[1]}_{post_id.split("_")[2]}_{post_id.split("_")[3]}')
                elif post_id.split('_')[0] == 'riddle':
                    post_info = get_info_into_DB('/home/nikita/bots/message_bot/DB/post_with_riddle.pickle').get(f'{post_id.split("_")[1]}_{post_id.split("_")[2]}_{post_id.split("_")[3]}')
        update = telebot.types.Update.de_json(json_string)
        bot.process_new_updates([update])
        return ''
    else:
        flask.abort(403)


# Handle '/start' and '/help'
@bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    global post_info
    global post_id
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,'OK')
    print(post_info)
    print(post_id)
    print(bot.get_chat_member(post_id.split("_")[2], message.from_user.id).status)
    if post_id.split('_')[0] == 'continuation' and bot.get_chat_member(post_id.split("_")[2], message.from_user.id).status != 'left':
        bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, open(post_info[0], 'rb'), caption=f'{post_info[2]}')
    else:
        keyBoard_post = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(True)
        keyBoard_post.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Подписаться', url = post_info[-1]))
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,'Для просмотра поста!\nПодпишитесь на канал!', reply_markup = keyBoard_post)    
    post_info = []
    post_id = ''

@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call:True)
def call_answer(call):
    print()
    bot.send_message(call.from_user.id,call.data)

# Remove webhook, it fails sometimes the set if there is a previous webhook
bot.remove_webhook()

time.sleep(0.1)

# Set webhook
bot.set_webhook(url='https://37.230.117.88/bot')

# Start flask server
app.run(host='127.0.0.1',
        port=7771)
```

Код uwsg

```
from post_bot import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Nginx конфиг

```
server {
         listen 443 ssl;
         listen [::]:443 ssl;
         server_name 37.230.117.88;
         ssl_certificate sites-available/rootCA.pem;
         ssl_certificate_key  sites-available/rootCA.key;

        location /bot/ {
            proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:7771/;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

    }

}
```

Comment: В коде бота, пробовали заменить 127.0.0.1 на 0.0.0.0?

Comment: Спасибо, я уже разобрался)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался, следовало указать путь к сертификату вот тут:

```
bot.set_webhook(url='https://37.230.117.88/bot')
```

Так как у меня самоподписной сертификат, это обязательно)